# rotating moving scaling of UIImageView moving inversly after rotating by 180*

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

Here is my code for moving,scaling and rotating the UI`ImageView` all work fine but the issue is when we rotate the `ImageView` it rotates but after then it move inversely like i am dragging toward right but the `ImageView` is going left 
cant we get the current center point after rotating so that we when we drag the center points are of that rotated `ImageView` not original one

this is the custom class inherited by `UIImageView`

```
#pragma mark Manipulation
-(void)scale:(id)sender {
    if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
{
        _lastScale = 1.0;
    }

    CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (_lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

    [self setTransform:newTransform];


    _lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
    [self showOverlayWithFrame:self.frame];
}


-(void)rotate:(id)sender {

    if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        _lastRotation = 0.0;

        return;
    }


    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (_lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

    [self setTransform:newTransform];
    _lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];

    [self showOverlayWithFrame:self.frame];





}


-(void)move:(id)sender {

    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self];

     if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
         _firstX = [self center].x;
         _firstY = [self center].y;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(_firstX+translatedPoint.x, _firstY+translatedPoint.y);

    [self setCenter:translatedPoint];


    [self showOverlayWithFrame:self.frame];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by changing this line in -(void)move:(id)sender just got my task done
>
> Older

```
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self];
```

> Correct

```
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:[self superview]];
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1. Use `CGAffineTransformTranslate` the same way you've been using `Scale` and `Rotate`.
2. Better yet, reset the affine transform, move the image view, then set the transform back.

Try this code for option 2:

```
CGAffineTransform t = self.transform;
self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
[self setCenter:translatedPoint];
self.transform = t;
```

Comment: Ok let me try both of these options

Comment: thanks for your but thats not making a nice feel check my answer now